# Arrange same custom Objects from arraylist in dart

Tags: list, dart, collections

I have an array of custom objects as below:-

```
"trackPointList": [
        {
            "latitude": 22.038446,
            "longitude": 88.085593,
            "serialNo": 5,
            "timeZone": "IST"
        },
        {
            "latitude": 22.038446,
            "longitude": 88.085593,
            "serialNo": 6,
            "timeZone": "IST"
        },
        {
            "latitude": 22.496401,
            "longitude": 88.323892,
            "serialNo": 7,
            "timeZone": "IST"
        },
        {
            "latitude": 22.496401,
            "longitude": 88.323892,
            "serialNo": 8,
            "timeZone": "IST"
        },
        {
            "latitude": 22.038446,
            "longitude": 88.085593,
            "serialNo": 9,
            "timeZone": "IST"
        },
        {
            "latitude": 22.038446,
            "longitude": 88.085593,
            "serialNo": 10,
            "timeZone": "IST"
        }
    ],
```

I have created a class **TrackPoint** for custom objects and a list

```
List<TrackPoint> trackingPoints;
```

I have filled the objects in the above list successfully. Now I want to gather same objects whose lat and long are same with other objects in a separated lists. For example in above case I want two list which contains 4 same objects in one list and other two same objects in separate list as per their latitude and longitude.

Apart from that if there are other different objects as per their lat and long then they should store in another list.

Please let me know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what this kind of operation are called so I ended up calling my implementation for `collectByCompare`.

The following implementation are an extension for the `List` class which allows to group up entries in the List which are equal by the `test` method you can give as input to the method:

```
class TrackPoint {
  final double latitude;
  final double longitude;
  final int serialNo;
  final String timeZone;

  const TrackPoint(this.latitude, this.longitude, this.serialNo, this.timeZone);

  @override
  String toString() =>
      '<latitude=$latitude longitude=$longitude serialNo=$serialNo>';
}

void main() {
  const trackingPoints = [
    TrackPoint(22.038446, 88.085593, 5, "IST"),
    TrackPoint(22.038446, 88.085593, 6, "IST"),
    TrackPoint(22.496401, 88.323892, 7, "IST"),
    TrackPoint(22.496401, 88.323892, 8, "IST"),
    TrackPoint(22.038446, 88.085593, 9, "IST"),
    TrackPoint(22.038446, 88.085593, 10, "IST")
  ];

  trackingPoints
      .collectByCompare((TrackPoint a, TrackPoint b) =>
          (a.latitude == b.latitude) && (a.longitude == b.longitude))
      .forEach(print);

  /* Output:
    [<latitude=22.038446 longitude=88.085593 serialNo=5>, <latitude=22.038446 longitude=88.085593 serialNo=6>, <latitude=22.038446 longitude=88.085593 serialNo=9>, <latitude=22.038446 longitude=88.085593 serialNo=10>]
    [<latitude=22.496401 longitude=88.323892 serialNo=7>, <latitude=22.496401 longitude=88.323892 serialNo=8>]
   */
}

extension<E> on List<E> {
  Iterable<List<E>> collectByCompare(bool Function(E, E) test) sync* {
    final handled = <E>[];

    for (final a in this.where((e) => !handled.contains(e))) {
      final result = this.where((b) => test(a, b)).toList();
      yield result;
      handled.addAll(result);
    }
  }
}
```